# Crazy orders HP calculation

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

In the final battle against crazy hand in crazy orders, player HP is based on damage taken and the hand's HP is based on the number of turns. But how does this work, exactly? Particularly, for player HP:

- What is the ratio between damage and HP?
- Does healed damage count towards the total?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The amount of HP you start with in the final fight against Crazy Hand is equal to `damage + 150`, where "damage" is the amount of damage you have at the time of selecting the "fight Crazy Hand" ticket.

[Source](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Special_Orders)